# How can I remove all non-numeric elements from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Integer(100));
    list.add(new Double(3.14));
    list.add(new Long(21L));
    list.add(new Short("100"));
    list.add(new Double(5.1));
    list.add("Kitty");
    list.add(new Integer(100));
    list.add(new Object());
    list.add("Snoopy");
    list.add(new BigInteger("1000"));
```

oh I guess its a very simple question...
i just want to remove non-numeric elements from an arraylist
only remain numeric elements
I think it has something to do with java.lang.Number

Thank you for your guidance master

Have a nice and happy day

Comment: Your list should be declared as `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>()`.  And depending on your Java version, some of your constructors are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.removeIf(e -> !(e instanceof Number));
```

Though it`s a bad idea to use List/ArrayList with no generic type specified and store different type objects in it.

Comment: "Though it's a bad idea to use List/ArrayList with no generic type" you might consider saying that `List<Object list = new ArrayList<>();` would be better.